# How to do a Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I need some help with a navigation bar! I want to make it horizontal and they're all seperate, kinda like the bit next to the stack overflow thingy, (where it says: questions, tags etc.).

I tried just doing a menu but I realised that treats it all as one, not seperate things, so I added divs and everything went askew when I altered the CSS to make sure it gets eeverything within the divs, so I reverted it back to it's original menu form.

Here's my HTML:

```
  <!-- navigation bar for: ALL PAGES --->
    <nav style="width=100%;">

    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Review</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Customer Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Leave a Review</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discounts</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Refer us!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Claim discount</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation bar for: ALL PAGES --->
```

and my CSS:

```
/* nav */

#menu {
margin:0 auto;
display: inline-block;
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
}

#menu li a {
font-family:helvetica;
display:block;
padding:10px 10px;
text-decoration:none;
}   

#menu li a:hover {

}

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;

}
#menu > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I did not get, what you need here I created a fiddle with your code, can you provide little bit clear what you need for ? http://jsfiddle.net/xr522ho9/

Comment: Sorry mate, the question is not very clear. Are you looking for something like [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/cujz3ydL/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this

[image]

Then use this

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    background:gray;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```